# Creating a Kotlin Multiplatform lib targeting all native targets using gradle

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

As the title suggest. I am trying to create a Kotlin Multiplatform library that targets all **native** targets. Currently I can create a library targeting a specific platform, say `ios`, `wasm`, `mingw`, `raspberrypi`, etc.

I know this is possible as there are some Jetbrains libraries that do exactly that. For example `kotlinx.serialization` has a **native** target which can be implemented like the following:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"
```

Also, one can use ktor client **native** libs like this:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-auth-native:$ktor_version"
```

So how do I target **all native targets** instead of a specific native target? How do I configure Gradle that it will produce one native target which can be served for all native targets?

Comment: I suppose you're talking about something like [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#experimental-metadata-publishing-mode)?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev That still targets a specific lib. I want to write a lib that targets all native targets

Comment: Please correct me, but I thought that you want to make a library the same way as serialization does. 
 `This publication does not include any artifacts and only references the other publications as its variants.` 
That's exactly the same thing.

Comment: Looks like you are not wrong, @ArtyomDegtyarev I do not fully understand what the kotlinlang site means by `publication does not include any artifacts and only references the other publications as its variants`, Do you mind to explain further? and if possible, show a minimal build.gradle sample for a multiplatform lib?

Comment: About the example of this approach - it's hard to find something not-so-complex. Consider looking at [this](https://github.com/h0tk3y/better-parse) or even serialization you mention(I know, that's not an easy one). The idea here sounds like that: when you add `kotlinMultiplatform` to your publications list, it should produce an umbrella artifact, that contains no code but reffers to other published artifacts. This means that you should produce the library for all artifacts separately, but there will be an extra one, making easier to consume your library. How does your script look for now?

Comment: Perfect explanation. Now I fully understand, let me look into `better-parse`

Comment: Please @ArtyomDegtyarev present your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. It works